# autocompletemode equivalent in system.windows.controls.combobox

Tags: wpf, autocomplete, combobox

I have an editable `combo-box` where the user could select (or type) one of the values from the `drop-down`, or a different value altogether.

I need the `autocomplete` functionality, which is essentially showing a subset of values in the drop-down when one or more characters are entered.

I see there is an [autocompletemode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode.aspx) property in `system.windows.forms.combobox`, which would have probably served my purpose but, is there an equivalent in `WPF system.windows.controls.combobox`?

Answer (score 0):

The [WPF Toolkit Autocomplete Box](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) is what you need. [This tutorial](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/02/wpfautocompletebox/) [should get you started](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/auto-complete-box-in-wpf-toolkit/).